# Migrating from Joomla 1.5.x to 1.7

Tags: joomla1.5, joomla1.7

I thought of migrating from J 1.5.23 to 1.7 and like almost everyone i too ran into problems (Good i backed-up my site)
The problem i am facing is that my jUpgrade gets stuck at 'Migrating undefined'. 1.7 gets downloaded completely and also extracts correctly. I think i am still facing this problem because i somehow run out of space during the installation. what i wanted to know was How much disk space does migration require?
I have like 25 Mb free on my server and i am allowed only 100 MB so.
Thank You?
and btw i also unchecked the skip downloads options, didnt work for me

Comment: Reason for voting down? I did search on the net and coudnt find an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will probably need more disk space than you have available. Your current site, plus the downloaded zip file, plus space for extracting the files plus any backups you have on the server are likely to exceed your 100MB.

I'd recommend taking a backup of your site, setting up the site on a localhost (xampp, wamp, etc) server on your own machine and run the migration there. This will have the benefits of not hitting arbitrary limits of what sounds like a very low budget web host.

Obviously you'll have the extra complexity of setting up your own server on your PC - but there are many tutorials out there that will walk you through the process, and the learning of new skills is always good.

Comment: ok so if i have like 40MB am i good to go then? Because i just freed some space on the server.i think the J1.5 is 23 mb in size or something..not sure though

Comment: The migration will copy your entire site into a subfolder - so the total disk space requirement will be 2*your current site's size plus space for the zip file plus space to unpack the zip file. Seriously - I would advise doing this on a localhost server with wamp, xampp or similar.

Comment: sorry for the late comment-i already have a local installation of joomla. So what you are saying here is that the size will be say around the size of my xampp folder? or only the htdocs? + the zips and space required for unpacking